Elementary OS 7.1 does not shutdown or reboot
I've installed elementary os 7.1 in HP zbook. And it doesnot shutdown or reboot, it just stays like this in the image even for days. Is there a solution for this?


press esc key, see if error message will appear or not. might be waiting for device/service/resource to be shutdown/disconnect.
